# ASP Hyperlink control using href="#" and validation

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I'm having an issue using the asp hyperlink control and the "#" href value.  I don't want the link to navigate away from the current page or reload it but I want the link to cause validation to happen to a specific validation group.

The following line doesn't trigger validation.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="next" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="SideRifStepOne" href="#">Next Step</asp:HyperLink>
```

If I use the same attributes for  the validation works but the page is reloaded.  Any suggestions for triggering validation without reloading the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be calling Page_ClientValidate() manually:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="next" runat="server" href="javascript:doValidate()">Next Step</asp:HyperLink> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function doValidate()
                    {
                        Page_ClientValidate();
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  It performs validation and does not postback.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

have you tryed using a linkbutton? you can set onclientclick="return false;" to prevent a postback and it should cause the validation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried and it doesn't load page nor validates.  If I remove onclientclick="return false;" it performs validation, and if it fails the tool tips show, however, if validation passes it refreshes the page.  With onclientclick its not validating.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `EnableClientScript="true"` to your validation control. By doing this the validation will be performed in javascript before a postback occurs.

Comment: Thanks, actually my validation controls do have the attribute.